# MySQL/PHP Coding Program

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have the following code which links my phpmyadmin database to my PHP script. The code takes a table of 50 NFL players with their stats of the previous season. Now, I want to be able to code it so that I can select a player via a drop down box or some sort of dropdown box/list like that and then when selected and the Table is shown again, that player will not be listed. However, I am stuck and am not sure how to do this. Could someone at least help me out with the basics and what I would need for this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title>PHP Project</title>
        <style>
            table,th,td {
                border: 1px solid navy;
                }
        </style>
</head>

<body>

<?php
    $db_hostname='localhost';
    $db_username='root';
    $db_password='';
    $db_database='Project';

    $connection = new mysqli(   $db_hostname,
                                $db_username,
                                $db_password,
                                $db_database);

    if ($connection->connect_error) {
        echo "Sorry";
    } else {
        echo "Connected!<br><br>";      
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM NFL2014Receiving";
        $result = $connection->query($sql);
        if (!$result) die ($connection->error);
        $n = $result->num_rows;     

        for ($i=1; $i<=$n; $i++) {
            $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        echo "<table>
            <tr><th>ID</th><th>Player</th><th>Team</th>
            <th>Position</th><th>Receptions</th>
            <th>Receiving Yards</th><th>Avg Yds/Catch</th>
            <th>Avg Yds/Game</th><th>Touchdowns</th></tr>";

        echo "<tr><td width=20>" . $row['iD'] . "</td><td width=150>" . $row['Player'] . "</td><td width=40>" .
                $row['Team'] . "</td><td width=30>" . $row['Pos'] . "</td><td width=30>" .
                $row['Rec'] . "</td><td width=40>" . $row['Yds'] . "</td><td width=30>" .
                $row['Avg'] . "</td><td width=40>" . $row['Yds/G'] . "</td><td width=20>" .
                $row['TD'] . "</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: while looping through your rows, save the `Player`/`iD` in an array, and then build a dropdown using those values. Then add a conditional that if the form is posted/a player is selected, that your query would include `WHERE iD != selectedPlayeriD`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<?php
    $db_hostname='localhost';
    $db_username='root';
    $db_password='';
    $db_database='Project';

    $connection = new mysqli(   $db_hostname,
                                $db_username,
                                $db_password,
                                $db_database);

    if ($connection->connect_error) {
        echo "Sorry";
    } else {
        echo "Connected!<br><br>";      
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM NFL2014Receiving";
        $result = $connection->query($sql);
        if (!$result) die ($connection->error);
        $n = $result->num_rows;     

        $nfl = array();

        echo "<table>
            <tr><th>ID</th><th>Player</th><th>Team</th>
            <th>Position</th><th>Receptions</th>
            <th>Receiving Yards</th><th>Avg Yds/Catch</th>
            <th>Avg Yds/Game</th><th>Touchdowns</th></tr>";

        for ($i=1; $i<=$n; $i++) {
            $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            $nfl[$row['iD']] = $row['Player'];
            if(!isset($_POST['hide']) || $_POST['hide'] != $row['iD']){
                echo "<tr><td width=20>" . $row['iD'] . "</td><td width=150>" . $row['Player'] . "</td><td width=40>" .
                        $row['Team'] . "</td><td width=30>" . $row['Pos'] . "</td><td width=30>" .
                        $row['Rec'] . "</td><td width=40>" . $row['Yds'] . "</td><td width=30>" .
                        $row['Avg'] . "</td><td width=40>" . $row['Yds/G'] . "</td><td width=20>" .
                        $row['TD'] . "</td></tr>";
            }
        }
        echo "</table>";
        echo "<form method='post' action=''><select name='hide'>";
        foreach($nfl as $key=>$value){
            echo "<option value='".$key."'>".$value."</option>";
        }
        echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit'>";
        echo "</select></form>";
    }

?>
```

Try it and let me know if it worked for you :-)

Comment: you have a syntax error(s) on `echo "<form method="post" action=""><select name='hide'>";`. (double quotes issues)

Comment: @Sean ah yes you are right i was typing it right in here. Thank you. I will fix it.

Comment: its giving me a syntax error in the echo statement with the post part in this code: `echo "<form method="post" action=""><select name='hide'>";`

Comment: Yes i edited it meanwhile. Its ok now there. Just use it like this : 
echo "<form method='post' action=''><select name='hide'>"; I had i typo there and instead of ' i used "

Comment: Yes i tried it and it worked...just what i needed...thank you!

Comment: You can check the answer that it was right then :-) So that anybody knows that this is the right answer for your question :-)